# how do i assign the arguments in the cleartool command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, clearcase

i have written the batch file as follows

```
v:
cd view/vob/component

set /p comment="enter comment: "
set /p base_line="enter baseline: "

cleartool mkbl -c "%comment%" %base_line%

cd\

c:`
```

even though i assign arguments the clear tool command cant taking it, please do any one know the solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a `echo "%comment%" %base_line%` before calling the cleartool